# Excel: Convert mass text to a number and maintain fixed length?

Tags: excel, text, numbers, fixed-length-record

I'm working with about a 1 million record data set.  Currently the data is formatted as the "text" type and I want it to be a "number" type.

I have used the copy special > multiply technique, but the conversion will drop leading zeros in the data set.  I do not want this, I want to maintain the fixed lengths of the data inclusive of leading zeros.

How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry, cannot help here, just stumbled upon the question, but you should probably add Excel or the DB you use to the tags for your question so that more/the right people will see it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the numbers to **appear** as, say `00125` instead of `125` in Excel? Or do you need to export the data in text format with the right number of characters? When you say "dataset" do you mean the data is stored in a database? etc.

Comment: @assylias Data is stored in Excel, and it will remain there as I need to run computations on it.  I just want to change the data from the "text" type to the "number" type without losing the structure.  I.E. it's formatted as 00125, but when I use the paste special > multiply technique I get 125.  I want it formatted as a number, but keep the original structure, 00125.

Comment: @TheSHEEEP Thanks for the input, but for some reason the Excel tag doesn't exist.  Due to my status level I can't add it.  I have a hard time believing that "Excel" doesn't exist, so maybe it was a bug.

Comment: @Addikt As you can see the excel tag has been added to your question: it does exist!

Comment: @assylias I saw that after I commented.  It prompted me to delete the "excel" and "conversion" tags, though.  Maybe I mis-spelled them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VBA code like the one below, but you still need to insert the logic that will format the i-th column with the right length.

```
Sub doIt()

    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To 10 'replace 10 by the index of the last column of your spreadsheet
        With Columns(i)
            .NumberFormat = String(.Cells(2, 1), "0") 'number length is in second row
        End With
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Could I have this reference a key row? Like check the 2nd row for a specific number?  The first column has the header names.  The second (temporary) row has the length of the field in decimal format, i.e. 4 should be 0000.

Comment: One final question regarding this.  Wouldn't it be Cells(2,i) not Cells (2,1)?  Just want to make sure before I run it as it takes time to run any macros on this amount of data.

Comment: no, `.Cells(2,1)` as it is relative to the first cell in that column, not an absolute reference.

Comment: I have added a line to turn off screenudpating - that should run fairly fast. Obvious recommendation: save your spreadsheet before running the macro.

Comment: Okay, this won't iterate through the rows though, will it?

Comment: It will apply the formatting to the whole column. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't realize it would select all values in the column column values. Thanks for the help assylias!  I'm going to have to figure out the relative cell reference in excel because from a logical standpoint that shouldn't iterate on it's own.  Putting a period in front of something makes it relative?

Comment: no it's just the syntax of a "Width" block. (So .Cells(2,1) refers to Columns(i).Cells(2,1) and .NumberFormat refers to Columns(i).NumberFormat).

Comment: Ahh, I see.  That makes sense, and this solution works very well.  Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @assylias One final question.  How do I skip a certain row?  I want to do 1-10, but skip rows 7 and 8.  How would I structure that part of the argument?  I tried to create an array, but then Columns(arrayname) won't work.

Comment: You could probably do it with a union of ranges but not in front of a computer now.If you ask a separate question tagged with excel, vba and excel-vba I'm sure you'll get an answer (copy the code to get better help).

Answer (score 2):

An option is to set the Cell Format to Custom:
 Format -> Cell -> Custom: Textbox "Type": max number of zeros

example: 00000 will display 52 as 00052

Note: Make sure the Cell Format is applied to all cells involved in your Paste Special.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I realize this, but I have 1027 rows, and all the number lengths are different.  I know the specific lenghts for each row, I just don't know how to do everything automatically rather than manually.

Comment: What rule could be use to match a Length with a row ?

Comment: Sorry, I may have misspoke.  The data is organized in columns.  Each column has a specific lenght associated with it.  I know these length requirements, but how do I do it for all rows in one shot rather than have to format each row individually?

Comment: Using some VBA Macro... CellFormat can be applied programmatically within a loop over columns.

Comment: @Addikt If I understand what you are asking for, you can simply select a whole column and apply the method proposed by Francis P. That will apply the formatting to all the cells within that columns. You still need to do it once for each columns if they have different formatting requirements.

Comment: @assylias That's the problem, I have 1000+ columns and they all have different format requirements.

Comment: @FrancisP Any idea on what something like that would look like?

Comment: @Addikt Until you explain how you know what is the format of a specific column (largest number in the column? length of the title? ...), it is difficult to answer your question

Comment: @assylias I've already said several times that I have the key that provides me with the length of the data.  All number fields are a specific length including zeros.  For example, I know col 1 = ##, col 2 = ####, col 3 = ##, col 4 = #########, etc.  All numbers are this SPECIFIC length, no more, no less.